# enable back browser button with onepage site

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I published this site: http://www.estyle.agency and I discovered that when I want to come back (history of the page) during the navigation with back browser button, I go out of the site. I tested it on Chrome, Firefox, IE, android etc. but nothing. Could anyone help me or give me a similar question (I'm a beginner and most questions I've read are difficult)

Answer (score 1):

Try Bootstrap: [Bootstrap Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

This will allow you to use your back button when navigating between the menu.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The answer is using Bootstrap's #Affix Javascript functionality. Bill Necka got it.

Your website is set up as a one page.  Meaning, all the links (about, contact, etc) all jump to a different part of the same page, rather than to another page entirely.  If you click the browsers back button, it will take you to the last website you visited.

One answer is to not click the back button because those links aren't what you would consider web page links, they are more like 'jumps' that move you to a different part of that same page.

Another answer is to make each link a separate page, although that would completely alter the nice website flow.

Comment: I know it's no easy but maybe there is a plug-in to make this.. I'm searching in this direction.